# Ordering elements from $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., k\}$ s.t. that the difference between $2$ consecutive elements is $0$ or $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations, recursion, inclusion-exclusion

> In how many ways can you order (with repetition) elements from $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ...,
> k\}$ in $s > k + 1$ spots such that the difference between $2$ consecutive elements is $0$
> or $1$?

These are some of my ideas:

- Define $s-1$ new variables (call them $m_i$) that represent the differences between $2$ consecutive numbers. Now think of the number of ways of ordering $0$'s and $1$'s across these $m_i$'s and the number of ways to get $a_{i + 1} - a_i = m_i$ where $a_i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., k\}$. The problem with this is that I'm not being able to account for the fact that the $a_{i + 1}$ for $m_i$ is equal to the $a_{i}$ for $m_{i + 1}.$
- Stars and Bars: Sum over all possible summations of the $m_i$'s listed above where all possible bounds on the variables are considered. In the best case, this perhaps yields nested sums.
- Principle of inclusion-exclusion: There are $s^{k + 1}$ total permutations, representing the universal set. Of these, I need to find the union of all permutations s.t. the difference between $2$ elements is not $0$ nor $1$. The number of sets and intersections to consider is making this a big challenge.
- Recursion: This has the problem of not necessarily being a linear constant-coefficient homogeneous relation which can reduce the likelihood of forming a general formula. Moreover, I'm unable to construct one.

Fundamentally, I'm unable to break down this question into accessible cases to work with.  What I find especially frustrating is that choosing a $0$ or $k$ gives $2$ possible choices for the next number while all the numbers in between give $3$ choices. Accounting for every case while the pattern changes sporadically is something I'm not being able to control.

Comment: What does it mean to "order with repetition"?  If you can repeat terms, there are infinitely many ways to do it, right?

Comment: @lulu There are $s$ spots so it’s finite. For example, $1, 1, 2$ and $2, 1, 1$ are different orderings for $s = 3$.

Comment: So, what are the rules?  Must you use all $k+1$ symbols?

Comment: @lulu Not necessarily

Comment: So, you aren't ordering those elements.  You are just making a string of length $s$ on those letters subject to the rule, right?

Comment: @lulu Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying. We can choose say $t$ elements from the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., k\}$ These $t$ elements can have multiplicities s.t. the sum of the multiplicities is $s$. We can now order those $s$ elements in whatever way we want (subject to the rule), giving a new permutation for each unique ordering. So we need to consider all possible values for $t$ and all possible multiplicities for a fixed $s$.

Comment: "ordering the elements" sounds like you are putting the elements in order, which is not at all what is happening here.  I'd phrase the problem as "take an ordered alphabet with $k+1$ characters.  How many words of length $s$ can you write subject to the condition that consecutive letters can't differ by more than $1$."

Comment: @lulu I invite you to edit my question.

Comment: There's an obvious recursion, if you specify the final character.  That, at least, lets you compute the result for many values of $s$.  Not sure one can do better than this.

Comment: @lulu As in setting the value for $k$?

Comment: No, $k$ is set. If $F(s,x)$ denotes the number of good strings of length $s$ which end in $x$ then, for $x\not \in \{0, k\}$ we have $F(s,x)=F(s-1, x)+F(s-1, x-1)+F(s-1, x+1)$.  Note this also holds for $0,k$ if you make $F$ vanish outside its natural domain.

Comment: As I mentioned, the $0, k$ are truly frustrating elements in this computation. Thanks for highlighting this recursion, however.

Comment: I would implement this and compute the answer, call it $F(s)$, for lots of values.  See if there is a pattern.  My guess (possibly wrong) is that there isn't a simple closed formula, but the recursion should be pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be stated in terms of graph theory. Consider the graph whose vertex set is $\{0,1,\dots,k\}$, where two vertices $x,y\in \{0,\dots,k\}$ are connected by an edge if and only if $|x-y|\le 1$ (meaning there is a loop joining every vertex to itself). Then your problem is equivalent to counting the number of walks of length $s-1$ in this graph (the length of a walk is the number of edges, which is one less than the number of vertices).

Let $A_k$ be the $(k+1)\times(k+1)$ matrix where $A_{ij}=1$ when $|i-j|\le 1$, and $A_{ij}=0$ otherwise. This is the adjacency matrix for this graph. It is well known that the number of walks of length $\ell$ from vertex number $i$ to vertex number $j$ in a graph with adjacency matrix $A$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^\ell$. Therefore, the answer to your question is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^k(A^{s-1})_{i,j}
$$
Equivalently, if we let ${\bf 1}=[1\;1\;\dots\;1]$ be the row vector with $k+1$ ones, then the number of sequences is
$$
{\bf 1}\cdot A^{s-1}\cdot {\bf 1}^\top
$$